# PHP Ignored on HTML Page

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble embedding my php inside my html. Im using the Bootstrap SB Admin template.

Here is my php, which is inside the `<body>`

```
<?php 
    $msg='<p>yo you yo</p>';
    echo $msg;
?>
```

No matter which method I try to insert my php, the page displays it incorrectly with my trailing `?>` and other items displayed to the webpage

[image]

other methods include using `<?...?>` as well as placing the php in other sections of the html page.

The only other reason I can think that this would not be working would be if the template is causing the issue.

Comment: add the full code.

Comment: You cannot add PHP code to a HTML file and expect it to work, it wont. You can, however, add HTML to a PHP file and it will all work fine.

Comment: The reason you are seeing it "attempt to process" PHP is because XML tags are denoted with the `<?` beginning tag. Your files need to have a `.php` file extension and be (pre-)processed into HTML by PHP, either over CLI or (as typically done) over a webserver. PHP 7+ supports the `-s` option which allows you to run a PHP web server, self-contained in PHP. Read more here: (PHP Server inside PHP)[https://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file needs to have `.php` as file extension, not `.html`. Otherwise PHP won't be parsed/processed.

Comment: oof thank you. I had been attempting using the `.php` file extension. I was confused why it was only displaying the script but that was because it wasnt opened on my local server. Again, thank you